Vernier Calliper Reading and significant figures
What if in Vernier Calliper the Vernier Scale division (zero mark) coincides with the Main Scale Reading(MSR) will we take 'n' as 0 or 10 in the formula Reading = MSR + LC (Least Count) x n?
1) If we take 'n' as 0 then the significant digits will be reduced.
Example  -
Vernier Scale division (zero mark) coincides with 4cm on the Main Scale.
Taking 'n' as 0.
Reading = 4cm + 0.01cm * 0
=> 4cm + 0cm (least significant figure = 1)
=> 4cm
Shouldn't the answer be 4.00(With 3 significant figures)
2) If we take 'n' as 10 -
The reading will not be correct.

You are just misunderstanding what to do in this situation. Vernier caliper readings are always to 2dp in cm, not to any sf.

Related Least count of Vernier

$n$ should be taken as zero only but no it will not reduce the number of significant figures.
The reading in your case will be recorded as $4.00$ and will have $3$ significant figures.
Least count of the verniers caliper will be the error. And so $4.00\pm 0.01$

In your example, n is 0.
Significant figures are not used by professional scientists, they are only a training tool for students. Instead, scientists directly state the uncertainty. For your example, the measurement would be written as "$4.00(1)$ where the number in parentheses is the numerical value of the standard uncertainty referred to the corresponding last digits of the quoted results." Or a less preferred method would be $4.00 \pm 0.01$
